# Динамическая структура данных заполненная объектами шаблона класса

Tags: c++, классы, структуры-данных

Здравствуйте. Возникла необходимость реализовать динамическую структуру (линейную) заполненную объектами шаблона класса, но так как параметры-типы бывают разными, то я создал динамическую структуру указателей на void, чтоб с помощью функции заполнять динамическую структуру.

Но теперь возник вопрос: есть ли способ получить доступ к нужному объекту? Или же возможно реализовать данную задачу более просто?

Код:

```
struct InfoForUI
{
    std::string name;
    void* VectorClass;
};

struct ListForClass
{
    InfoForUI info;
    ListForClass* next;
};

class UIforClass
{
public:
    ListForClass *head;
    UIforClass() { head = NULL; }
    ~UIforClass();

    void Add()
    {
        //тут интерфейсная часть
        Vector <char> *obj = new Vector <char>;
        std::cin >>*obj;
        temp->info.VectorClass = obj;
    }
};
```

Прощу помочь советом.

Comment: Не понятно. Ты хочешь создать однонаправленный список, который будет хранить указатель на произвольный тип и некоторое имя? Если да, то для поиска нужного элемента надо пройти список последовательно. Можно ввести хэш таблицу и ускорить этот поиск. Можно хранить элементы в массиве, как в `std::vector`. А чем STL не устраивает?

Comment: SuperDimin007, динамическую структуру любую можно взять.  Основной вопрос у меня возник во время извлечения самого объекта. Каким образом я могу обратиться к методам данного класса? И возможен ли более простой способ реализации?

Comment: Я, вроде, основные методы извлечения перечислил. Можно ещё использовать деревья.

Comment: Скорее всего, вашу задачу можно решить иначе. Но не эту, а исходную. Поэтому, если не секрет - зачем вам такой способ хранения? Что вы хотите делать с этими объектами? Почему их надо все хранить в одной коллекции? По сути ваша задача примерно такая - есть массив указателей на `int`, `double` и прочие, а потом надо, например, для `k`-го элемента определить тип, да еще и не просто определить, а именно динамически во время выполнения... Думаю, надо менять сам подход. Нельзя ли, например, свести исходную задачу к хранению объектов иерархии классов с виртуальными методами?

Comment: @Harry, я создаю интерфейс для демонстрации шаблона класса с созданием его объектов, а так же изменением их, используя методы самого класса. Собственно,  я решил выделить для этого структуру,  но так как я сомнительно видел определение параметра-типа в этой структуре,  то решил использовать пустой указатель.

Comment: Ну, а зачем "впихивать невпихуемое" в одну емкость? Что это демонстрирует? Покажите свои классы отдельными объектами...

Comment: @Harry,я пытался реализовать интерфейс с неограниченным количеством этих объектов. Для этого использовал структуру данных. 
Не уверен,что `Vector <char> *obj = new Vector <char>; temp->info.VectorClass = obj;` работает корректно. Вариант моего решения - создавать объект, записывать его адрес в массив указателей, а при необходимости изменения объекта, получать его по нужному адресу. Столкнулся с проблемой лишь в последней части, так как не нашел способ получения нужного объекта по его адресу (чтоб можно было использовать его методы).Есть ли какой-то вариант это сделать или же лучше переделать?

Comment: Ну, что я придумал - в ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Откровенно говоря, не придумалось ничего лучшего, чем сделать базовый абстрактный класс, в который внести виртуальные функции, с которыми вы хотите работать, и держать в списке адреса на базовый класс. Что-то типа

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void out() const = 0;
};

template<typename T>
    class Test :public Base
{
public:
    Test(T t):t(t){ cout << __func__ << "@" << t << endl; }
    ~Test(){ cout << __func__ << "@" << t << endl; }
    void out() const { cout << __func__ << "@" << t << endl; }

private:
    T t;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Test<int> t(5);
    Test<double> v(6.6);

    vector<Base*> b {&t, &v};
    for(auto x: b) x->out();
}
```

Сюда при желании можно приплести и `dynamic_cast`, если уж очень захочется передавать параметры соответствующего типа...